# Combinatorial proof of an identity involving binomial coefficients $\sum_{k=3}^n {k \choose 3} = {n +1\choose4}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-proofs

My problem is that I need to give a combinatorial proof to show both sides are equal for this equation:

$\sum_{k=3}^n {k \choose 3} = {n +1\choose4}$

I have simplified it into:
$\sum_{k=3}^{n} \frac{k!}{3!(k-3)!} = \frac{(n+1)!}{4!(n-3)!}$

I understand that (especially when summed) $k! = (n+1)!$ and $(k-3)(n-3)!$ but I don't understand how to show that these two equal each other and what to do with the $4!$.

Comment: How did you simplify? Please provide more details. Note that combinatorial numbers are well defined for $N\geq n$ in $\binom{N}{n}$, so for $k=0$ $\binom{0}{3}$ seems strange...

Comment: This is known as the [hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity).

Comment: @NicolasAgote honestly I dont know why I changed the sum I saw someone else do it in a different question so I thought it applied here

Comment: Careful: when changing the range for which we are computing the summation, we should also change the inner expression so the same terms appear. In this case, if we want to sum over the range $0,\cdots n-3$ we can take $j=k-3$ and then we have that $\sum_{k=3}^{n} \binom{k}{3} = \sum_{j=0}^{n-3} \binom{j+3}{3}$.

Comment: Actually, for $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, $\binom{n}{k}$ exists for all $n\in\mathbb{C}$. $\binom{n}{3}=\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{3!}$. For $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $0\le n\lt k$, we get $\binom{n}{k}=0$.

Comment: I was not familiar with the extension to complex numbers, thanks @robjohn! However, for combinatorial proofs that deal with counting simple sets I have never found it necessary to use this extension. You got me curious now: do you know an example where it can be of use?

Comment: @NicolasAgote: $(1+x)^\alpha=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\binom{\alpha}{k}x^k$ is valid for any $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ and $|x|\lt1$.

Answer (score 1):

@robjohn already provided one most adequate link to Wikipedia's article on the identity. Still, I wanted to provide some ways in which one can try to come up with such combinatorial proofs.

When we look at the right side of the identity and we will see only one combinatorial number, which is counting the ways in which we can choose $4$ elements from $n+1$. Now we can try to interpret the left side of the identity as *another way* of counting how to choose $4$ elements from $n+1$.

Look at the left side of the identity, and you will find:

1. a summation, which indicates that while counting we have decided to separate in different cases, and
2. combinatorial numbers, which suggest that we are choosing from $k$ elements subsets of $3$.

Can you now come up with an explanation of how the left side of the identity counts the ways of choosing $4$ elements from $n+1$?

As provided by @robjohn, one [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity#Proof_2) these tips may have made us suspect existed.